# Android GCM Registration fails with AUTHENTICATION_FAILED exception

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm Trying to register to GCM to use push notification.
For most of the devices it works, and I can get the push notification with not problem, but on 2 devices, I get

> "IOException (@GoogleCloudMessaging:register:-1)
>   {AUTHENTICATION_FAILED}"

I don't understand why this happens, can someone advise?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
I've tested the account user-id and password and they are correct (and the gmail is synced) and the google play services is up to date

Answer (score 3):

The GCM requires a user to have a google account configured in device. Please check it once if you have the google account configured in your device properly with accurate User-ID and Passwords.

Along with a valid Google account configured you also need to have the Google play services to be installed. To get the google Play Services installed on your device click [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)

Comment: Thanks for your response. however, this is not the issue, I've tested the account user-id and password and they are correct (and the gmail is synced) and the google play services is up to date

Comment: GCM no longer requires a Google user account on Android 4.0.4 and above. Source: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest `GCM API` , then it could possibly be due to missing `Google play services app` in your device, that is a must.